# Need a workaround to access ReadOnlySpan<T> inside a function that returns an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable, yield-return

While dealing with native code interoperability, I decided it was the time to learn and try new Span features of the C# language.

Although with many trials, everything was going perfectly fine until I come to the final stage of my very long function for which I insert below just a minimal reproducible sample:

```
[DllImport(dll, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern void GetNativeData(out byte lpBuffer, int size, out bytesRead);

ReadOnlySpan<T> ReadArray<T>(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buf, int Length) where T : unmanaged
{
    var size = Length * Unsafe.SizeOf<T>();
    if (buf.Length < size)
        buf = new byte[size];
        GetNativeData(out MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buf), size, out int read));
        Dh.CreateError(ReadMemoryErr);

    return MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(buf.Slice(0, size));
}

static IEnumerable<MyClass> GetResult()
{
    // Here I allocate a buffer
    Span<byte> buf = new byte[1000];

    // After a long serie of calls to unmanaged DLL functions I end up with something like this:
    ReadOnlySpan<uint> uintRes = data.ReadArray<uint>(buf, 10);
    ReadOnlySpan<ushort> shortRes = data.ReadArray<ushort>(buf, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < uintRes.Length; i++)
    {
        // Any access to spans inside this loop result in Error CS4013
        string r = GetFunRes(uintRes[i]);
        IntPtr r2 = GetFunRes2(shortRes[i]);
        yield return new MyClass() { Prop1 = r, Prop2 = r2 };
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> Error CS4013: Instance of type 'Span' cannot be used inside a
> nested function, query expression, iterator block or async method

Now, I have read that there [are workarounds](https://endjin.com/blog/2019/10/dotnet-csharp-span-and-async) for this. The articles only shows usage for async methods, but it also states that applies to iterators. Unfortunately I have not been able to make this work. I only need to read specific elements of the span and then, yield a result that does not contains any element or reference to the span. It's just that whatever I try to, as soon as I try to access something the compiler fails.

I have read about `Memory<T>`, and may be that this one could work, but I have some concerns, because I have read that the performance is dramatically reduced. People also recommend Span at the first place. I hope I can find a solution because otherwise I will have to restart from scratch my project and rewrite everything, because now is tightly tied to Span.

> @00110001:

> `var uintRes = data.ReadArray<uint>(buf, 10).ToArray();`

> I know that this will work, but I suppose that it will make Span usage useless along with the new generics unmanaged features I am trying to take advantage of (`ReadArray<T>`). If I am not wrong, calling ToArray() it's the same of the old Marshaling style where a new copy is created for each call:

> `internal static extern void GetNativeData(out uint[] lpBuffer, int size, out bytesRead);`

> @Ian Kemp
> This is how I tried the workaround mentioned in the article:

```
int len = uintRes.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   var res = ParseData(i);
   if (res == ExpectedResult())
      yield return res;
}
MyClass ParseData(int index)
{
     // CS8175: Cannot use ref local 'uintRes, shortRes' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression
     string r = GetFunRes(uintRes[index]);
     IntPtr r2 = GetFunRes2(shortRes[index]);
     return new MyClass() { Prop1 = r, Prop2 = r2 };
}
```

Comment: You might want to give more specific examples as in your current code, you  need neither `Span` nor `Memory`.

Comment: Obviously you cant use an iterator method, a class will get generated the span will be captured as a property and it will end up on the heap.... Return an array ? or a list, allow the caller to use use a loop instead of calling into an iterator method. Or just use toArray to pass into the iterator.

Comment: BTW, if the memory has been allocated on heap, you might just return the `Span` itself, rather than iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the post with a more specific example along with more details. I never had chances to play with "Memory<T>" and I never felt the need to use it because all APIs have mostly SPAN overloads. However, I noticed that I can access a buffer allocated with "Memory<T>" inside my iterator, but my concerns remain (and I suppose that if I use Memory all of my work around Span will be kicked off and only for just the need of an iterator).

Comment: `but I have not been able to make this work` then it sounds like you should be asking a question with the specifics of what "does not work", instead of this one. I see nothing in the linked article or your code that indicates the local non-async method approach could not work for you.

Comment: @Ian Kemp You're right! I really don't know how I have missed that part! I just updated the post with how I have tried to implement the workaround. Thanks

Comment: @IanKemp The articles states that it also applies to iterators, but when trying to access through a "local non-yieldable" method I get error CS8175 and I don't know why because the local method should allow the ref struct type as showed in the article. That code can access the Span, but my code can't!

Answer (score 21):

The gist is in [this article](https://medium.com/@antao.almada/how-to-use-span-t-and-memory-t-c0b126aae652). Basically, in order to use IEnumerable with yield, `Memory<T>` is needed because `Span<T>` is a ref struct that is allocated on the stack and can't be used across yield boundaries.

On the other hand, `Memory<T>` can reside on heap while still providing `Span<T>` access. The author of the article shows the maximum that can be done with pure Span and the sample code required in order to enable IEnumerable with [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) along with the benchmarks of the different implementations.

`IEnumerable+memory<T>` is very slow compared to the other solutions, but for anyone who still want LINQ, I recommend to look at [NetFabric.Hyperlinq](https://github.com/NetFabric/NetFabric.Hyperlinq), an alternative version of LINQ developed from the same author of the article in order to fill that gap. I am not sure if even with this solution will still persist a big difference with for/foreach loops combined with pure Span, but I suppose it mainly depends from the number of calls, type of queries, etc. (see [LinqBenchmarks](https://github.com/NetFabric/LinqBenchmarks) to see how each query performs).

P.s. If the article is unreachable, there is [a web archive capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109031211/https://medium.com/@antao.almada/how-to-use-span-t-and-memory-t-c0b126aae652).

Comment: Thank you for documenting the solution you found and providing helpful resources! In case you don't need other answers, feel free to mark your own answer as the accepted answer so the question is "closed" :)